# Ubuntu find and delete files newer than created Date X

Tags: shell, ubuntu

To find all files where has creation date -5 days or OLDER is this command:

> find /path/to/files* -mtime +5

But how can I find these files where has creation date 08/01/2016 or NEWER?
And how can I delete this files?

Answer (score 3):

To find all files created 5 days ago or NEWER you can use this command:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime -5
```

If you instead need to specify a specific DATETIME, you could use, for example:

```
find /path/to/files* -newermt $(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '3 hours ago')
```

in `-d` flag argument you can use any string describing an absolute time.
Please note that `newerXY` is a relatively new extension.

Comment: and how can I select for an specific date or newer?

Comment: Do you mean a specific date-time, not just raw days?

Comment: yes ... like in my question: how can I find these files where has creation date 08/01/2016 or NEWER

Comment: See my last edit.